# Read CSV - Memory Issue

Tags: asp.net, csv

Easy question. I need to read a CSV file in .NET, and for that I'm using the Lumenworks CSV library. 
The problem is that it seems this solution reads the entire CSV content into memory. I was wondering if there's another option that would let me run through the CSV content one element at a time, and therefore, consume less memory.

Something like XmlDocument vs. XmlReader.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [StreamReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) to load the file line by line to do some operations like searching, matching, etc., with the method [StreamReader.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) Method. One sample is contained in it to show how. This really costs little time.

Store the position or line number after once of operation, then in the next operation use the [Stream.Seek Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to start load from the stored position.

Comment: I like this option. But don't forget that you might need to manage the first row, which could contain (or not) your header, aka your column information.